# Keep the correct lane on road

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, geometry

I am trying to make a Traffic Simulator for my bachelor thesis.

I created a map with `OpenStreetMap osm` and now I am trying to put some cars on roads.
I created a graph for the roads. The graph is like this:

```
A->B,C,D
C->A,B,E
B->A,C
D->A
E->C
```

and I generate random the cars on random points A,B,C,D,E,F. After this I use function `getShortestPath(start,end)` to get the shortest path for every car and I put the cars to move:

```
foreach(Car c in allCars){ 
    Move(c,path) 
 }
```

But, I have a problem, I don't know how to keep the correct lane of road for every car, all my cars are on the same lane of road.

I am thinking about the direction between two points and the car will be at the right side of the direction.
But I have no idea how to do this....

Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, the problem is that you are only thinking about the shortest path, but this function have the logic to calculate the direction of the car? if yes, just duplicate the paths and assign a direction, if not, you need to rethink your "getShortestPath" algorithm

Comment: in my driving simulator i have a class RoadNetwork with an array of RoadSection objects (they represent the road from one crossroad to the next) and each RoadSection has an array of RoadLane objects and each RoadLane has an array of Vectors that represent the center curve. each RoadLane has 2 RoadLane references - `from` and `to`. when i calculate the shortest path i use these `from` and `to` references, so that cars always drive on the correct side of the road.

Comment: i forgot - just recently i made a RoadConnection class that has 2 RoadLane references - `from` and `to` and each RoadLane has 2 RoadConnection objects. this was a small change, but the code looks better now.

Comment: it seems to me that the simplest way to solve this is to include the `position` in `from` and `to`

Comment: My "getShortestPath" algorithm return the best path from two points. I dont need more from this algorithm. Bijan, can you explain what are thinking about?

Comment: Since your cars have their own direction why not just offset the position? based off of their transform.right?  if a car is going from a to b then his transform.right is different then a car going from b to a. so for example you do `position = mathf.lerp(a.Point, b.Point, progress) + transform.right;`

Comment: My code is this:  car.car.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(car.car.transform.position, car.path[car.index].point + lane, Time.deltaTime * speed); lane is (0,2,0)

Comment: @RãzvanZavalichi tbh I would change the way you are doing your updates especially if you are updating positions with `car.car.transform.position` to something where each car updates itself... but if you are limited on time and dont want to make to many drastic changes then I would find a way to store that position something like `car.car.progressPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(car.car.tprogressPosition, car.path[car.index].point + lane, Time.deltaTime * speed);`  then update the car position with `car.car.transform.position = car.car.progressPosition + car.car.transform.right;`...

Comment: @Eddge I did what you say but desn't work. This code is in void Update(). My cars are moving only to the right. Should I use this code before and after update ?

Comment: @RãzvanZavalichi I would have to see specifically how you added it..

Comment: Vector3 progressPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(car.car.transform.position, car.path[car.index].point + lane, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        car.car.transform.position = progressPosition+transform.right;  Can I update the file somewhere for you ?

Comment: @RãzvanZavalichi yea that isn't what I said, specifically look at the MoveTowards first parameter.

Comment: @RãzvanZavalichi you are using the position with the offset, rather then the progressPosition,  you need to save off the progressPosition in each car, then update that cars positions with that + the transform.right

Comment: @Eddge Hmm, I need something like this Class car{  my variables;  Vector 3 progressPosition; } tprogressPosition is another variable or is a mistake that "t" ?

Comment: @RãzvanZavalichi its a typo you can ignore that t.  My bad.

Comment: @Eddge progressPosition should be the current position for car? I said: car.progressPosition=car.car.Transform.position; then: car.car.progressPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(car.car.progressPosition, car.path[car.index].point + lane, Time.deltaTime * speed);

Comment: @Eddge Here is my code https://ufile.io/46fig

Comment: @RãzvanZavalichi unfortunately I cant see that, you would have to add it to your original question... if it is a screenshot, but I am posting an answer with what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to update your movement and car code, taking into account our conversation in the comments.

Add a variable to your car class:

```
Class Car {
   // your other variables
   Vector3 progressPosition;  // This will only be set to the from nodes position whenever you get a new path.
}
```

Your update code will be like this:

```
void UpdateCarMethod()
{
    car.car.progressPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(car.car.progressPosition, car.path[car.index].point + lane, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    car.car.transform.position = car.car.progressPosition + car.car.transform.right;
}
```

Comment: @RãzvanZavalichi I will take a look at your file when I am in a place I can grab it, then I will update my answer.

Comment: now it is working, but just for moving the car from A to B. If the path is A,B,C,D the car will stop at B. My condition to find if the car moved from A to B is: if (car.car.transform.position == car.path[car.index].point + lane)
        {
            if (car.index < car.path.Count - 1)
                car.index++;
            else //code for generate another path

Comment: It's working :X.. Thank you sir, you arre the best. Now if i whant that distance between cars to be a little bigger I need to do this: car.car.transform.position = car.car.progressPosition + car.car.transform.right*2 ?

Comment: @RãzvanZavalichi yes